# Replace word in php var

Tags: php, replace

I'm trying to replace a word in a php var, but it isn't working the way i'm trying.

Here's my code:

```
iframe.src = '<?php echo $app->url("Widget:iframeContent") ?>&domain=' + document.domain;
```

It'll return this:

`http://127.0.0.1/livechat/php/app.php?widget-iframe-content&domain=' + document.domain`

Here's what i tried:

```
iframe.src = '<?php echo str_replace("http", "https", $app->url)("Widget:iframeContent") ?>&domain=' + document.domain;
```

What I want to do is replace the http with https, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: You can't find the `str_replace()` function?

Comment: What is "the way I'm trying"? I don't see any attempt to replace a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the way you're calling the `url` method when you added the call to `str_replace`; you have the argument to `$app->url` outside the call. It should be:

```
iframe.src = '<?php echo str_replace("http", "https", $app->url("Widget:iframeContent")) ?>&domain=' + document.domain;
```